# Retrieve multiple using OData in CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, json, dynamics-crm-2011, odata

I want to retrieve multiple record. Here is my code;

```
function GetQuoteDetails(quoteId) {
var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();
var ODATA_ENDPOINT = "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc";
var odataSetName = "QuoteDetailSet";
var odataSelect = serverUrl + ODATA_ENDPOINT + "/" + odataSetName + "$filter=QuoteId/Id eq guid'" + quoteId + "'";
var jSonArray = new Array();
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "json",
    url: odataSelect,
    beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) { XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json"); },
    success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
        if (data && data.d != null) {
            jSonArray.push(data.d);
        }
    },
});
return jSonArray;
}
```

It returns nothing. But there should be 4 records returned. Where is the problem?

Comment: What does plugging your odataSelect url into a browser give you?

Comment: your code is asynchronous, probably you check jsonArray before the success function is executed

Answer (score 0):

Since this is Asynchronous call, you cannot return from function GetQuoteDetails. For verification either use Console.log or alert to check what is data.d value.